# Runs on 2.2 but crashes in Android 3.0

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I started out making an app for android 2.2 but now changed to Android 3.0.
The app runns fine on 2.2 but when I run it on 3.0 it crashes.
Eclipse do not find any errors.

Are there stuff in 2.2 that is not included or in 3.0?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: I just activated logcat and now it works. Hmmm, strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I was making a network call in the main thread. 
This seems not to be allowed in Android 3.0 Honeycomb. 
I solved the problem with making the network call in an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

When you do any modification of the title bar like

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

and say target version = 11 , it will crash as those things are not compatible with the ActionBar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It just fixed it self somehow when I started logcat. =)